# Optimize this long nested If statement in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Please help me to optimize this long If statement in Kotlin. I want to make it shorter as much as possible.

```
`if (locationType == 1) {
        if (isPostDayOfWeeks) {
            if (isPostLocation) {
                Log.d("RefreshStatus", "PostLocation: " + isPostLocation)
                settingRepo.setLocationStatusText(true, endTime.toString())
            } else {
                if(isPostNextDayOfWeek()){
                    settingRepo.setLocationStatusText(false, startTime.toString())
                }else{
                    settingRepo.setLocationStatusText(false, null)

                }
                Log.d("RefreshStatus", "PostLocation: $isPostLocation")
            }
        } else {
            settingRepo.setLocationStatusText(false, null)
        }
    } else {
        if (autoLocationSwitch) {
            settingRepo.setLocationStatusText(true, null)
        } else {
            settingRepo.setLocationStatusText(false, null)
        }
    }`
```

Comment: `if (autoLocationSwitch) {
            settingRepo.setLocationStatusText(true, null)
        } else {
            settingRepo.setLocationStatusText(false, null)
        }`. You can change that `settingRepo.setLocationStatusText(autoLocationSwitch, null)`. And so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this help?

```kotlin
val (X, Y) = when {
    locationType != 1 -> autoLocationSwitch to null
    !isPostDayOfWeeks -> false to null
    isPostLocation -> true to endTime.toString()
    isPostNextDayOfWeek() -> false to startTime.toString()
    else -> false to null
}
settingRepo.setLocationStatusText(X, Y)
```

Replace `X` and `Y` with proper names.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this if clean or readability matters :

```
if (locationType != 1) {
  settingRepo.setLocationStatusText(autoLocationSwitch, null);
  return;
}

if (!isPostDayOfWeeks) {
  settingRepo.setLocationStatusText(false, null);
  return;
}

if (isPostLocation) {
    settingRepo.setLocationStatusText(true, endTime.toString());
    return;
}

settingRepo.setLocationStatusText(
  false,
  isPostNextDayOfWeek() ? startTime.toString() : null
);
```

Must wrap this code in method otherwise it may block some code to execute!

Comment: Thanks , Good answer. Please also see 1st answer with   Kotlin "When" statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables with default values to elide some of the branches:

```
boolean location = false;
String time = null;
if (locationType == 1) {
    if (isPostDayOfWeeks) {
        if (isPostLocation) {
            Log.d("RefreshStatus", "PostLocation: " + isPostLocation);
            location = true;
            time = endTime.toString();
        } else if (isPostNextDayOfWeek()) {
            time = startTime.toString();
        }
    }
} else {
    location = autoLocationSwitch;
}
settingRepo.setLocationStatusText(location, time);
```

Comment: Thanks , Nice answer. Please also see 1st answer with Kotlin "When" statement.